# Not possible to load the blockchain in multibit so can't pay or recieve either till it's loaded

Tags: multibit

```
"C:\Users\Pompen\AppData\Roaming\MultiBit".
 "C:\Program Files\MultiBit-0.5.18".
Unable to load blockchain "C:\Users\Pompen\AppData\Roaming\MultiBit\multibit.spvchain". The error was "com.google.bitcoin.store.BlockStoreException Corrupted block store: could not find chain head: 0000000000000000139072ad82693ddc93b29fca541778907aced232b031072b".
Opening wallet "C:\Users\Pompen\AppData\Roaming\MultiBit\multibit.wallet"...
... done
Opening wallet "C:\Users\Pompen\AppData\Roaming\MultiBit\Naamloos.wallet"...
... done
```

Then it shows these messages:

> Starting blockchain replay from network...
>
> Replaying blockchain from date "7-May-2015"
>
> Stopping Bitcoin network connection...

And this error:

```
**17:56:34.604 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-2] ERROR org.multibit.network.ReplayManager - Cannot download blockchain as there is no PeerGroup**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of this support note on multibit.org which looks like it covers that error:

https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_support_blockStoreException.html

> BlockStoreException
>
> You see a BlockStoreException very occasionally when MultiBit starts. It prevents you synchronising with the Bitcoin network.
>
> You can fix this problem by doing the following:
>
> 1. Find where MultiBit is storing your user data - see the help topic [Troubleshooting](https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_troubleshooting.html)
> 2. Shut down MultiBit
> 3. Go to your MultiBit user data directory - worked out in step 1 - and delete the file multibit.spvchain
> 4. Start up MultiBit again
>
> It will then regenerate this file and start syncing. After it has synced you should see all your bitcoin in your wallet..